# Add several Formulas in the specific columns using Macro up to the bottom of the list

Tags: vba, excel

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

1. insert the formulas (Formula #1, #2 & #3) in cell G2, H2 & J2.
2. copy those formulas (inserted in cell G2, H2 & J2) and drag it down up to the bottom of the table.

[image]

some useful information:
- The number of rows are dynamic. this means that monthly, it changes. the minimum # of rows historically is 60,000 rows.
- the amounts in column b to F under the names of the persons also changes. sometimes, it's blank (just like in my example).

I have **coded** a macro using the excel macro recorder, but it fails it's very very slow. 20mins before it completes a 100,000 rows. is there a faster code for this?  is it possible if someone could help me how to:

1. insert the following formulas that starts in column G, H and J.
2. copy that formula up to the bottom of the list and then stop?

is that possible?

here's my code:

```
Sub Formula()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long


    Set rng = Range("A2:A1048576")
    For Each cell In rng
        'test if cell is empty
        If cell.Value <> "" Then

            cell.Offset(0, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC[-6]:RC[-2])"
            cell.Offset(0, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-5]:RC[-1])*0.5"
            cell.Offset(0, 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-9],RC[-8],RC[-7],RC[-6],RC[-5],RC[-4])"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll bet this is fast:

```
Public Sub DC1(ws As Worksheet)
  Dim lastrow&, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
  lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  Set rng1 = ws.Range("A2:A" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
  Set rng2 = rng1.Offset(0, 6)
  rng2.Formula = "=AVERAGE(RC[-6]:RC[-2])"
  Set rng2 = rng1.Offset(0, 7)
  rng2.Formula = "=SUM(RC[-5]:RC[-1])*0.5"
  Set rng2 = rng1.Offset(0, 9)
  rng2.Formula = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-9],RC[-8],RC[-7],RC[-6],RC[-5],RC[-4])"
End Sub
```

EDIT: added lastrow
EDIT2: added ws parameter; .Formula instead of .Value.
Without the ws parameter, it defaulted to the ActiveSheet.
If calling from sheets, Sub DC1 has to be in a standard module.

Comment: Quick question.. what if i want this macro to run in sheet 1 then i want a button in sheet 2. Is there any changes in the codes? Actually, i tried what ive mentioned and the macro fails to run. I think there should be a little modification in the codes..

Comment: @Kareen Lagasca - It should've worked if Sub DC1 was in a standard module. I assume you had `Call DC1()` in your button code. For the above edit you can `Call DC1(Me)`. (Accept if it answers).

Answer (score 0):

Excel evaluates each new formula it sets - this is why it takes such a long time for the code to finish. To get around this problem you can just set the formula for the entire range at once - assuming that the formula is copyable.

For example `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G2:G100000").Formula = "=SUM(B2:F2)*.50"` works just fine, **G3** will have a formula `=SUM(B3:F3)*.50` and so on.