# Excel Macro to run on a different Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that should run on SHEET1. then I have another sheet (SHEET2) where it holds a button for the user to click to be able to run the macro. My question is, I assigned the macro in my button but nothing happens. I tried adding this line `Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & lastrow)` but the macro stops and completely finish the tasks. Is there something wrong with my code? Please help.

```
Sub DC1()
  Dim lastrow&, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
  lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  Set rng1 = Range("A2:A" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
  Set rng2 = rng1.Offset(0, 6)
  rng2.Value = "=AVERAGE(RC[-6]:RC[-2])"
  Set rng2 = rng1.Offset(0, 7)
  rng2.Value = "=SUM(RC[-5]:RC[-1])*0.5"
  Set rng2 = rng1.Offset(0, 9)
  rng2.Value = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-9],RC[-8],RC[-7],RC[-6],RC[-5],RC[-4])"
End Sub
```

Comment: @Nanashi - This reminds me of something.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761536/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. Qualify your sheets. Because the macro is called from a button in `Sheet2`, the ranges are instantiated from that sheet instead of `Sheet1`.
2. Use `.FormulaR1C1` instead of `.Value` if you're going to use an `R1C1` notation formula.

Here's a fixed version of your code.

```
Sub DC1()

    Dim WS1 As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range

    Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With WS1
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng1 = .Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        Set Rng2 = Rng1.Offset(0,6)
        Rng2.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC[-6]:RC[-2])"
        ' ... Other code.
    End With

End Sub
```

Let us know if this helps.